# Bad positioning of "All posts" / "All tags" buttons in user profile after orientation changes

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, ios-app

**Description:**

In the site-specific user profile of any user, the "All *n* posts" and "All *n* tags" buttons are sometimes positioned wrongly, after I change the orientation of the device between portrait and landscape.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Open the left drawer, then tap any site.
2. Go to the Users tab, then tap any user to go to the user's network profile.
3. Under the user's avatar, tap any site to go the user's site-specific profile.
4. Now change the orientation of the device between portrait and landscape. Sometimes, the position of the "All *n* posts" and "All *n* tags" buttons become wrong.

**Actual Results:**

Sometimes the buttons are near the middle.
Sometimes the buttons are invisible.

**Expected Results:**

The "All *n* posts" and "All *n* tags" buttons should always be aligned on the right, just like the "All *n* sites" in the user's network profile.

**Environment:**

- Stack Exchange iOS App v0.1.25
- iPhone 5
- iOS 7.1

**Screenshot:**

Good:
[image: screenshot good]

Bad:
[image: screenshot bad]

Half good half bad:
[image: screenshot half good half bad]

Comment: +1 for the nice, symmetrical smileys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for a well-written bug report.
This issue indeed was related to the layout of the right text ("All xx posts") element after a device rotation.

This will be fixed in **version 0.1.26**.

Comment: Verified fixed in 0.1.26.